# template specialization for static member functions; howto?

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I am trying to implement a template function with handles void differently using template specialization.

The following code gives me an "Explicit specialization in non-namespace scope" in gcc:

```
template <typename T>
static T safeGuiCall(boost::function<T ()> _f)
{
    if (_f.empty())
        throw GuiException("Function pointer empty");
    {
        ThreadGuard g;
        T ret = _f();
        return ret;
    }
}

// template specialization for functions wit no return value
template <>
static void safeGuiCall<void>(boost::function<void ()> _f)
{
    if (_f.empty())
        throw GuiException("Function pointer empty");
    {
        ThreadGuard g;
        _f();
    }
}
```

I have tried moving it out of the class (the class is not templated) and into the namespace but then I get the error "Explicit specialization cannot have a storage class". I have read many discussions about this, but people don't seem to agree how to specialize function templates. Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you specialize a templated method, you must do so outside of the class brackets:

```
template <typename X> struct Test {}; // to simulate type dependency

struct X // class declaration: only generic
{
   template <typename T>
   static void f( Test<T> );
};

// template definition:
template <typename T>
void X::f( Test<T> ) {
   std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}
template <>
inline void X::f<void>( Test<void> ) {
   std::cout << "specific" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   Test<int> ti;
   Test<void> tv;
   X::f( ti ); // prints 'generic'
   X::f( tv ); // prints 'specific'
}
```

When you take it outside of the class, you must remove the 'static' keyword. Static keyword outside of the class has a specific meaning different from what you probably want.

```
template <typename X> struct Test {}; // to simulate type dependency

template <typename T>
void f( Test<T> ) {
   std::cout << "generic" << std::endl;
}
template <>
void f<void>( Test<void> ) {
   std::cout << "specific" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
   Test<int> ti;
   Test<void> tv;
   f( ti ); // prints 'generic'
   f( tv ); // prints 'specific'
}
```

Comment: hm I tried the same thing now, but put it in a .hpp file and tried including it... then I get the error "multiple definition of vodi X:ff<void> (Test<void>). I can't see what would be the difference?

Comment: Was it a compiler or linker error? If it was a compiler error it means that you are probably including the template header more than once and the header guards are missing, and thus the double definition: the compiler is seeing two (alas exactly exact) definitions for the implementation.

Comment: Why shall I add inline for the first case? If not, i am getting an error of compilation.

Comment: @sop: I am not sure what the first case refers to... template functions don't need `inline`, template specializations need it if you put the definition in the header (to avoid ODR violations)

Comment: It is about the specializations; if I move it from header to .cpp (and still have the template in header), I am still getting the error of multiple definition or << not defined for string (aka char*).

Answer (score 5):

You can declare the explicit specialisation in the same way you'd define a member function outside of its class:

```
class A
{
public:
  template <typename T>
  static void foo () {}
};

template <>
void A::foo<void> ()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For me it doesnt matter if they're inside a class or not; but I cant make it work either way. Is my syntax wrong or something in the code I supplied?

Comment: The point is that you explicitly specialize the function in the namespace with a qualified function declarator.  C++ doesn't allow you to re-add the 'static' keyword so you just remove it.  My example above shows you how to explicitly specialize a static member.

Answer (score 4):

It's not directly an answer to your question but you can write this

```
template <typename T>
static T safeGuiCall(boost::function<T ()> _f)
{
        if (_f.empty())
                throw GuiException("Function pointer empty");
        {
                ThreadGuard g;
                return _f();
        }
}
```

It should work even if _f() return 'void'

Edit : In a more general case, I think we should prefer function overloading instead of specialization. Here is a good explanation for this : http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

Answer (score 2):

Your problem appears to be with boost::function - the following specialisations work:

```
template <typename T>
T safeGuiCall()
{
    return T();
}

template <>
void safeGuiCall<void>()
{
}

int main() {
    int x = safeGuiCall<int>();     // ok
    //int z = safeGuiCall<void>();  // this should & does fail
    safeGuiCall<void>();            // ok
}
```

Comment: sorry tried this but does not work. Did you compile under gcc? I think it works under VS for example...

Comment: It's thise statics - remove them and all should be weel, it compiles with comeau, I'll update the answer

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. If you look at the original post, I left the first static in, but took out the second and BOTH errors went away.